# How to convert svg string to svg file using Python?

Tags: javascript, python, django, svg

Using AJAX I send a svg image to Django using the following function:

```
function uploadSVG(){

    var svgImage = document.getElementById("SVG");

    var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    var svgStr = serializer.serializeToString(svgImage);

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.post("ajax_upload_svg/",
      {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
        svgImage: svgStr
      },
      function(){
        console.log('Done')
      });
    });
}
```

In Django I end up with the svg image as a string using the following function:

```
def uploadSVG(request):

    svgImg = request.POST.get('svgImage')

    return HttpResponse('')
```

The string I get looks like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="SVG" width="460" height="300" style="border:2px solid #000000"><rect x="150" y="70" width="160" height="130" fill="#292b2c"/></svg>
```

How can I convert this svg string into a svg file?

Comment: Just save it as an SVG file would be my guess.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:

```
with open("svgTest.svg", "w") as svg_file:
        svg_file.write(svgImg)
```